# three or more fields in same form - how to add/remove blank fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have three separate fields within the same form.  I would like to have the ability to dynamically add/remove blank fields for each one.

Here's the fields and a JQuery segment - that does work for the very first field but not the others.    What do I need to do?   I've also tried putting the 2nd .append statement into the first one,  that did not work either.

I also threw an alert into the 2nd one to see if it would trigger.  It does, but the button call does not work.

If I can get the first 2 fields to work, how do I handle the third one?  Like I said, the very first one works fine.

Fields

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="submitterEmail">  
        Email<g:field type="email" name="submitterEmail" class="form-control" required="" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterEmail-label"/><button id="add">Add+</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">  
        Fax<g:field type="text" name="submitterFax" class="form-control" required="true" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterFax-label"/><button id="add2">Add+</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
        Specimen<g:select name="specimen" from="" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="specimen-label"/>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when the Add Filed button is clicked
    $("#add").click(function (e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the div
        $("#submitterEmail").append('<div><g:field type="email" name="submitterEmail" class="form-control" required="" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterEmail-label"/><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
    });
});    
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when the Add Filed button is clicked
    $("#add2").click(function (e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the div
        $("#submitterFax").append('<div><g:field type="text" name="submitterFax" class="form-control" required="" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterFax-label"/><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');    
        alert('this is an alert test)       
    });    
});    
});
```

Comment: Your buttons have the same id. That would be why the second one isn't working.

Comment: actually I've tried it both ways.  Renaming the second one as "add2" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
<?php ?>// you can remove this tag.
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when the Add Filed button is clicked
    $("#add").click(function (e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the div
        $("#submitterEmail").append('<div><input type="text" name="submitterEmail" class="form-control" required="" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterEmail-label"/><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
    });
});    
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when the Add Filed button is clicked
    $("#add2").click(function (e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the div
        $("#submitterFax").append('<div><input type="text" name="submitterFax" class="form-control" required="" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterFax-label"/><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');    

    });  

$("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
    });  
});      

</script>
```

Html part.

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="submitterEmail">  
        Email<g:field type="email" name="submitterEmail" class="form-control" required="" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterEmail-label"/><button id="add">Add+</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" id="submitterFax">  
        Fax<g:field type="text" name="submitterFax" class="form-control" required="true" value="" aria-labelledby="submitterFax-label"/><button id="add2">Add+</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
        Specimen<g:select name="specimen" from="" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="specimen-label"/>
</div>
```

Comment: your example doesn't work quite right for me.  The first add button works and adds the fields.  But the second one does not; it doesn't add the fields and it kicks me up to the beginning of the field.

Comment: i have edited the answer now try the first two fields will add a input field with delete button.i don't know what you meant by kicks me up to the beginning any way try this.I have written for first two fields you can add in the same way for third.

Comment: I tried your new fix and I get the same problem. The first add button works just fine -- adds fields with a delete button which also works.  But the 2nd add button does not work; when add2 is clicked it does nothing.  I double-checked the button names and they match in the correct places, but the 2nd one does not function.

Comment: i'm editing the code with entire data just give the name to the file as something.php or something.html and run in browser, it will work it is working for me. the second text field is also coming.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues in my office also came up with this alternative fix if anyone is interested....maybe a little bit more involved perhaps, but also works nicely with some Bootstrap elements and formatting.  If it helps someone (it helped me!), then I'm glad to share it.

```
var counter = 0;

function addContactEmail(){
    $("#submitterEmailTbody").append('<tr id="submitterEmail'+counter+'Row"><td><input type="text" name="submitterEmail" class="form-control" required=""/></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteContactEmail('+counter+')" onkeypress="deleteContactEmail('+counter+'); return false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>');
    counter++;
}
function deleteContactEmail(id){
    $("#submitterEmail"+id+"Row").remove();
}

function addContactFax(){
    $("#submitterFaxTbody").append('<tr id="submitterFax'+counter+'Row"><td><input type="text" name="submitterFax" class="form-control" required=""/></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteContactFax('+counter+')" onkeypress="deleteContactFax('+counter+'); return false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>');
    counter++;
}
function deleteContactFax(id){
    $("#submitterFax"+id+"Row").remove();
}
```